# I want to change my default perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to change my perl in Linux, but even after exporting `PATH` it still shows perl version 5.8.8 when I use `perl -v`.

I want to use perl 5.6.1 and it resides in this location `/appl/Enablement2/perl_5_6_1`

What is the command to achieve this?

Comment: What does `which perl` tell you?

Comment: Which perl returns the following /usr/bin/perl

Comment: Ok, so that's the first `perl` command that the shell finds when it searches your path. Perhaps you have `/usr/bin` in your path before your `/appl/Enablement2/perl_5_6_1` directory?

Comment: Yes the perl 5.8.8 resides in that directory. But I need to switch or export the perl 5.6.1 without uninstalling the 5.8.8 or deleting it..

Comment: Maybe your perl is really in `/appl/Enablement2/perl_5_6_1/bin`, not just `/appl/Enablement2/perl_5_6_1`.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Please post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding directories to the `PATH`, you must include the *complete* path to the binary. So in your case, `perl` is really in `/appl/Enablement2/perl_5_6_1/bin`, not just `/appl/Enablement2/perl_5_6_1`, so you must:

```
export PATH=/appl/Enablement2/perl_5_6_1/bin:$PATH
```

Note also that if you want your perl 5.6.1 to be found first, it must be listed before the rest of the directories in `$PATH` (particularly `/usr/bin`, because you have another perl installed there). The shell runs the first binary it finds.

Answer (score 0):

How did you export the `PATH`?

If you append `/appl/Enablement2/perl_5_6_1` to `$PATH`, `/usr/bin/perl` will be invoked
so to use 5.6.1, you should export like this:

```
export PATH=/appl/Enablement2/perl_5_6_1:$PATH
```

Comment: I tried this exact line but when I try perl-v it still shows another version

Comment: did you get any error when you ran `export PATH=PATH=/appl/Enablement2/perl_5_6_1:$PATH`. Try this one: `echo $0; echo $PATH; which perl; /appl/Enablement2/perl_5_6_1 -v`

Comment: Actually I am new to linux and do not understand what you mean by append, I have just been typing out that command directly, do I need to do something else first ?